# How to create custom JSON with WebMatrix's Json Helper?

Tags: .net, json, code-first, webmatrix, helper

So far I've seen the basic use for the WebMatrix's Json Helper, like in [here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/160/WebMatrix-Working-With-The-JSON-Helper) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json%28v=vs.111%29.aspx). Those examples show how a List can be converted directly into a simple JSON, but I'm wondering how can I create a more customized JSON.

What I'm saying is that those examples encode a List into a JSON that looks like this:

```
[
  {obj1_property1 : obj1_value1,...}, 
  {obj2_property1 : obj2_value1,...}, 
  ...., 
  {objN_property1 : objN_value1,...}
]
```

What I want to create is something as follows :

```
{
  customProperty1 : customPropertyValue1, 
  customProperty2 : customPropertyValue2, 
  entries : [
    {obj1_property1 : obj1_value1,...}, 
    {obj2_property1 : obj2_value1,...}, 
    ...., 
    {objN_property1 : objN_value1,...}
  ]
}
```

How can I create this kind of JSON with the Json Helper? Or do I need to use something else? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find a better way, then it's pretty easy to set up a standalone razor page .cshtml like the following.  The URL then directly returns a JSON string.

```
@{
    // write whatever C# code is necessary to get object data
    ...
}

{
    "customProperty1":"@cp1",
    "customProperty2":"@cp2",
    ...
}
```

Comment: but if I have a List<T> with several objects, how am I supposed to display them?